# Cant login to onedrive with microsoft buisniss account

Tags: windows, onedrive

I opened a free trial of windows for buisness account, Im trying to login to my onedrive account but I get this:

[image]

And after a few minutes I'm getting this:

[image]

I tried with desktop app, I'm getting this:

[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

You should start checking if your Windows 10 is totally updated (including the optional updates), and rebooting your system, as well as checking through Microsoft Store if OneDrive is up to date.

Comment: But I loggen in via browser, how is that related to my windows version, that;s a new account from yesturday

Comment: I see. I realized you were using Microsoft OneDrive's app. In that case, if the online version isn't working, the first thing you could try is to use the desktop version as I mentioned before.

Comment: Regarding the error code, it's like an Internet connection issue. Here are some references:
Thread - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odstart-odsignin/error-code-0x8004de40/1783b60e-128d-462c-8040-c44717658489
Thread - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odstart-odsignin-sdwin10/onedrive-not-signing-in/34b6e7ca-a9b0-4b58-b07f-a78e269f5f49
Have also a look to this video: https://youtu.be/Rj78UT0byEQ.

If the issue remains, please share your OneDrive for Business sync client version number. Right click the icon > settings > About > version.